# Running a script inside a loop - echo file names

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a basic script that runs inside another script. I call `mass_split.sh` which then invokes `split_file.sh`. The `splite_file.sh` takes two arguments `-s file_name.txt` and `-c 1` (how many slices to cut the file). However I trying to run a loop to find all text file names in directory `./`  and then input the results to the `cut_file.sh` . I am getting no results back and then text files are not being split.

mass_split.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in ./*.txt
do
sudo bash split_file.sh -s echo "file '$f'"; -c 10
done
```

Comment: Your use of `sudo bash [script] ...` indicates to me that you're not 1) setting the script executable or 2) using a magic shebang, otherwise it would read `sudo ./split_file.sh ...`. (applies to split_file.sh, not mass_split.sh which we can see the shebang for)

Comment: You don't need the echo part. I'd suggest in the for loop the following instead of what you have:
`sudo bash split_file.sh -s $f -c 10`

Comment: the `-c10` part after the `;` will return: command not found. Drop the `;` Also, when I exclude the `bash split_file.sh ...` (because i don't have that command nor the code) it lists the files perfectly. You might as well show the code for `split_file.sh`. It might help.

Comment: @thom it takes echo as the file name and not the value passed in

Comment: @hesham_EE that works with your solution

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student Yes, but at least the code you show here does work. The part that does not work is `split_file.sh -s echo "file '$f'"; -c 10` within the context of this code (even if you would drop the `;`). Show us `split_file.sh` otherwise ther is no way of telling where the error is.

Comment: @thom you and hesham_EE were correct about dropping ';`. I went along with hesham_EE comment and took out echo. Could either of you provide it in answer format so I can accept the solution.

Comment: @hesham_EE see comment above please

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student take a look a at the answer from 'Wug', he was there all along. Give the guy the credits ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Code_Ed_Student. I was late in reading your comment. A side note, if you'll write shell scripts more, I think you need to study it further as your question indicates lack of 'shell proficiency' :) Best wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this has something to do with that errant semicolon after the string literal, which is almost certainly not doing what you want (unless you have another executable that you're intentionally running called `-c`).